# How to redirect to another action using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a view in my asp.net mvc 5 application, where the view shows a table with all orders that customers gave in. I want to make that when a user clicks on a row in the table, to redirect to a "details" action displaying all details about the order using jquery. This is my view..

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tr>
    <td>Customer Name</td>
    <td>Phone Number</td>
    <td>Watch Model</td>
    <td>Order Status</td>
    <td>Order Location</td>
</tr>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var order in Model.Repairs)
    {
        <tr class="row-click" data-repair-id="@order.Id">
            <td>@order.Customer.GetName()</td>
            <td>@order.Customer.PhoneNumber</td>
            <td>@order.Watch.Model</td>
            <td>@order.Status</td>
            <td>@order.Location</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

and this is my jQuery

```
@section scripts
{
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".row-click").on("click",
        function() {
            var element = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("Details", "Repairs")',
                data: { id: element.data("repair-id") }
            });
         });
    });
 </script>
}
```

and this is the action in "Repairs Controller

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var repair = _context.Repairs.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);
        return View(repair);
    }
```

And the problem is that when I click on the row nothing happens.

Comment: What is not working in your current code?

Comment: when i click nothing happens. I tried to see if the event listener is working, and it is (I made it alert something after click, and it worked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your jquery ajax section and replace with below instead:

```
var eleId= element.data("repair-id")
var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Repairs")';
url = url + '?id=' + eleId;
window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: it doesn't recognize the variable eleId.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I fixed it in my answer.

Comment: thanks that's it! I just had to do it a drop differently because the routing is /controller/action/id. so I just did "url = url + '/' + eleId". Thanks a mil.

Comment: Also, for better performance you should change your event handlers to apply on table like `$('#table').on('click', '.row-click',function()`

Answer (score 0):

abe you can also use the following Example for the same result

**jquery code:**

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    $('#SubmitName').click(function () {
        var url = "/Home/WelcomeMsg";
        var name = $('#Name').val();
        $.get(url, { input: name }, function (data) {
            $("#rData").html(data);
        });
    })
</script>
```

**Controller code:**

```
public string WelcomeMsg(string input)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        return "Please welcome " + input + ".";
    else
        return "Please enter your name.";
}
```

Source/useful link: http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ajax-get-and-post-calls-to.html

Hope it will be helpful kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks
Karthik

Comment: Is this for a full page reload or just for part of the page.

Comment: since we are using  $.get() which is the shorthand for $.ajax() get method ,it is just a part of the page reload. thanks karthik